# How to replace the Options Menu icon with a Letter Programmatically

Tags: java, android

I am working on an android application and I want to change the icon of the Options Menu to a letter, but in programmatically way, I want to make it a letter like "A",

[image]

according to this image how to change icon number 3 with programmatically way, 
please anyone can help me.

Comment: I think there is no solution for doing this programmatically: “The curious case of the Overflow Icon Color” by Martin Bonnin https://link.medium.com/2srsc4ZEKU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the overflow icon by:

```
val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.your_vector_drawable)
mToolbar.overflowIcon = drawable
```

And then set `mToolbar` as support action bar.
Now to replace it with a letter or a number I think you've to first create the vector drawable or a png of that.

Comment: thank you it's working, I just use this code and convert the text in SVG and use it